# The type or namespace XXX could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on a project that targeting .NET 4.0 Framework. I added a reference to a third party dll file and call its methods in my code and have no error. But when I build the project it gave me The type or namespace error with blue underline on the methods of the dll. Using .NET Reflector I checked dll .NET Version of mscorlib.dll it is 4.0.0.0. My application Target .NET Version is 4.0 then Why I'm getting this error.
What I have done.
Remove all references to the library. Clean the project. Restart the project. again add the references. Not good in English please guide me. Stuck in it last 4 days.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have privileges to access the dll file. Then try running Visual Studio as administrator. If it does not help try to build the solution as 64x/86x not Any CPU.

Comment: Nothing happen same issue